# Trying to remove unwanted space in a table,

Tags: magento2, css, table

I'm trying to create a 6 cell table on my site that contains 3 images and i want the corners of the three images to touch, with no boarder or padding. I've tried everything I can think of but everythng I've tried has resulted in unwanted spaces.[image: I've added an image of the page as it currently is]

this is the code that I'm using [image: an image of the code in the backend]

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Use div instead of table

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have to make sure those cells (i.e. `td`) do not have any paddings.

Another tricky point is that by default each `img` would have some small whitespace beneath it. You have to add `display: block` to the `img` to remove that whitespace.
(Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5804256/image-inside-div-has-extra-space-below-the-image)

```
td {
  padding: 0;
}

td img {
  display: block;
}
```

Live demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/21b3ujmk/